# how to detect username and password than login to different page

Tags: php

```
 <?php

if (isset($_POST["loginbtn"])){
    $euser = $_POST["Emp_Username"];
    $epassw = $_POST["Emp_Password"];

    $check_user = mysql_query("select * from employee where Emp_Username = '".$euser."'          and Emp_Password= '".$epassw."'");

    if ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($check_user)){
        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = "true";
        $_SESSION["eid"] = $row["Emp_ID"]; // keeps the member id in a session
       header("location: profile.php"); // proceeds to the profile page
    }else{
    ?>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        alert("Invalid Username or Password");
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: it only detect username and password
i want detect "position" inside the "employee" table to login to others page

Comment: You're trying to create a login that redirect's to another page that only that user can see?

Comment: Why one need to username and password when they can drop your database or login without username and password ___sql injection___ warning

Comment: the problem is if the employee got 3 type of position , i want to login to different page by detect the position...how?

Comment: Check the position type of the employee from your select statement and then do a if/elseif condition to test for the different account types and then do your header location for each one

Comment: @NullPoiиteя plus the plain text password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need another if condition inside your block code:

```
if (isset($_POST["loginbtn"])) {
    $euser = $_POST["Emp_Username"];
    $epassw = $_POST["Emp_Password"];
    $check_user = mysql_query("select * from employee where Emp_Username = '".$euser."' > and Emp_Password= '".$epassw."'");

    if ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($check_user)) {
        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = "true";
        $_SESSION["eid"] = $row["Emp_ID"]; // keeps the member id in a session

        if (in_array($row["position"], array("CEO", "Manager", "...")) {
            header("location: profile.php"); // proceeds to the profile page
        }
    }
}
else { ?> alert("Invalid Username or Password");
```